# Authentication Issue: Passport.js Local Strategy Not Redirecting to Profile Route

Tags: node.js, authentication, express-session, passport-local, connect-mongo

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on an authentication system using Node.js, Express, and Passport.js with the Local Strategy. Despite providing valid credentials during login, I'm facing an issue where the application doesn't redirect to the profile route as expected.

Problem:
After entering the correct username and password, the application doesn't redirect to the /profile route as specified in the successRedirect option of passport.authenticate. Instead, it redirects back to the /log-in route.

Code Snippets:
Here are relevant parts of my code:

```
// passport.js
passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(async (name, password, done) => {
        try {
            const user = await User.findOne({ name: name });
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect Username" });
            }
            const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
            if (!passwordMatch) {
                return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
            }
            return done(null, user);
        } catch (error) {
            return done(error);
        }
    })
);
// 

// app.js
// login : post
app.post(
    "/log-in",
    passport.authenticate("local", {
        failureRedirect: "/log-in",
        successRedirect: "/profile",
    })
);
```